# Visual Studio C++: what's creating these threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2008, thread-priority

I've been using threads for 20 years on Unix and just learning them on Windows, with Visual Studio 2008.

My app is dialogs-based MFC GUI, with four main "peer" windows (none of them a "main" window).  When MyApp::InitInstance() starts, the Debug->Windows->Threads window reports just a single thread, MainThread.  As I step past the *first* `CDialog::Create()` call, 3 worker threads are created.  I don't know what these are and would love to--and especially would love a reference to a full explanation book or web page.  I tried putting a breakpoint on `CreateThread()` but VS2008 reports: `The function cannot be found.` in the hover over the `!` icon in the Breakpoints window.  I also cannot single-step into it if I break in a function that calls it.  I assume its a system call and as kernel code VS08 can't reach into it.

I then create a worker thread that outputs audio and is set to THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL.  This has worked stably for a long time.

However once my app leaves MyApp::InitInstance(), there is a **mystery thread** created with "Priority" shown as -8 in the Debug Threads window.  I don't know what that thread is.  Any ideas or pointers to resources?  I tried putting a breakpoint on `SetThreadPriority()`, assuming that I'd hit that in whatever code is setting it to this non-vanilla priority, and just as `CreateThread()`, it isn't a known function.

And on to the actual issue, as opposed to mere mystery: in shutting down my app, I'm destructing and freeing all the memory I used, and getting a crash in this "-8" thread while I do so.  There's no source, just assembly, and no stack trace or symbols.  There's no hint from the program that its heap corruption, such as symbols appearing on on its stack or the Output window.

The only extra info I can think to give about the app is that:

-- it receives MIDI events fine and has for years

-- it has one worker thread, calculating data for a sound buffer; I set a sentinel boolean flag and wait for it to end with `GetExitCodeThread()`; I indeed get the exit code so I'm sure this isn't the -8 thread.  (And its priority is "TimeCritical" anyway, not -8)

-- everything is problem free except for memory leaks, which I'm addressing now using `_CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC` .  Without freeing data, I'm not having the crash.  But having found out what exact object is causing the problem, I'm still at a loss because--again--I haven't actually created a thread that refers to that object.

Comment: This is really difficult for me to answer without seeing some actual code. Are you *creating* threads in your project? In other words, these 4 dialogs that you have, are you trying to display them on separate threads? That is not going to work well, all UI should occur on a single thread.

Comment: Probably just a threadpool, rather likely when you tinker with a multi-media api.  Or shovelware that gets injected into your process.  Let's not have to guess at this.

Comment: As documented, [CreateThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453.aspx) is almost always the wrong API to use. Call `_beginthreadex` instead. Apart from that, Windows processes usually create additional threads, e.g. for the debugger (implemented in kernel32.dll), or DDE. And when you say *"crash"*, what really do you see? It may just have triggered a debugger breakpoint, that pops up a dialog.

Comment: Thx guys.  Other than the one audio thread, I am not trying to create any threads.  I single-step the debugger past the call to Create() in a CDialog subclass and bang, three new threads.

Sure, a thread pool, I understand that, but what are they used for and where are they documented?

There's no multi-media per se in the app.  I am using the low-level audio functions you can find starting at `waveOutOpen()` though.  (You give me one idea: if that is creating threads, they'd probably be destroyed with `waveOutClose()`.  I could see  such a thread continuing to use memory a dead thread gave it

Comment: Those threads aren't documented, because they are implementation details. Your code does not need to know about them. If you are thrashing heap memory, it's nothing to do with extra threads created by the system. And you still haven't explained, what you really mean when you say that you are *"getting a crash"*. Is it a debug assertion? An uncaught SEH exception? A debugger breakpoint? All of these display dialogs that developers commonly confuse with a *"crash"* (whatever that is supposed to mean anyway).

Comment: You can try to break on exceptions. `Debug | Exceptions...`, if I correctly recall.

Comment: Thx ZDF.  VS08 **is** breaking on exceptions, which is how I see it:  Apologies for not explaining clearly enough what the mode of failure was.

Comment: Hans, what do you mean by shovelware?  Freeware or shareware libraries I've downloaded?   If so, no, its a 40,000 line app I've written myself--the bugs are all mine.

Comment: "Your code does not need to know about them."  Fair enough @IInspectable.    I'll agree that in general one shouldn't know or care about such a thread, just as most humans would never know or care they had an appendix.  But when troubleshooting why your lower right side suddenly hurts, is it not reasonable to start asking questions?  In this case the mystery thread kept generating access violations, and despite some suggestions that I didn't need to worry about what the thread did, finding out what created it lead instantly to the answer.

Comment: "As documented, `CreateThread` is almost always the wrong API to use. Call `_beginthreadex` instead."  Thanks for the pointer, but googling around and searching StackOverflow itself I'm not seeing much information on why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to your help in figuring out how to breakpoint the thread creation.  It became instantly clear that it was being created inside the audio processing library.  As one gives that library a block of memory containing samples to play, and I had free'd that was the prime candidate.

Reading between the lines of the Microsoft documentation, I found two additional functions that might potentially shut down such a thread (to wit `waveOutReset()` and `waveOutClose()`.  After calling those, the access violations have disappeared.  With this type of bug its hard to be positive, but for me this seems like a likely cause of the problem.

For years, the program simply exited upon user command, without deallocating storage, and didn't have issues.  It was only upon adding cleanup code that the problem became visible.  These facts also support the suspected cause.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of libraries, including MFC, create extra worker threads or thread pools as part of their normal operation.  It's nothing to worry about.

If you really want to know exactly where those threads are getting created, the problem with your setting the breakpoint on `CreateThread` is that the debugger can't resolve the symbol name.  You need to help it out by telling it what module it's in by using the special syntax `{,,module}symbol` (more info about that [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ce_base/archive/2005/11/30/tips-for-using-breakpoints.aspx)).  Additionally, the name might be decorated, so the actual symbol name that works might be any one of `{,,kernel32.dll}CreateThread`, `{,,kernel32.dll}_CreateThread}`, or `{,,kernel32.dll}_CreateThread@44`.  Likewise for `SetThreadPriority()`.

I'd also strongly recommend configuring the debugger to [use the Microsoft symbol servers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416588%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#using_the_microsoft_symbol_server), if you haven't already.  This will give you a lot more helpful symbolification of function addresses within Microsoft DLLs (including MFC), to give you a better idea of what it's doing.

That said, knowing where that thread is being created is likely not going to help you.  You most likely have some kind of heap corruption going on due to a buffer overflow somewhere.  When you free a buffer which has been overflowed, the corruption is going to get worse, because the heap manager is going to follow corrupted pointers and start writing into other random places of memory; whereas not freeing corrupted buffers is less likely to crash the process.  Tracking down exactly where the heap corruption is happening is going to be challenging.

Comment: Thanks about decorations--I've never seen anything like that in 25 years on Solaris/Linux or 5 on  Win32.  I wonder how I got this far without it.  Thanks also about symbol servers.

I thought seeing where the thread was created might help in understanding what its doing.

Yes--corruption is a distinct possibility, but if so I'm surprised the MSFT _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC routines aren't detecting it at some point, and they seem to always do so in the MAIN thread, not this mystery -8 priority thread.  (BTW you have no ideas about that?; your other info blows me away.)

Comment: @SwissFrank: Name decoration is common with all C++ compilers, and most C compilers decorate names as well. Not sure why you ignored this in the past 25 years, assuming that you have been writing C++ code.

Comment: What you say about name decoration is true in general, but I don't think the Win32 API functions are decorated in any way (other than `A` and `W` suffixes on those functions that take strings parameters). If they were decorated, using `GetProcAddress` correctly would be far more difficult. It's a boon to debugging, too.

Comment: > Name decoration is common with all C++ compilers.  @IInspectable, thanks for your comment.  I know name mangling of course.  I've not heard it termed decoration before.  If memory serves, all the mangling I've seen is postfix, not prefix, and has never involved curly braces.  Also, debuggers almost invariably accept the un-mangled name visible to the programmer.  If the programmer can write CreateThread that's usually good enough for the debugger.  Its this combination that rates a "I've never seen anything like that."  In contrast I've actually submitted bug fixes for gdb for mangling.

Comment: @Swiss Adam is not saying that the mangling involves curly braces. The curly braces are part of the commands you give the debugger. The mangled function names would be simply `_CreateThread@44` or whatever. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) on name mangling is pretty decent; it would be a good refresher and has a useful comparison table on the strategies used by different compilers. Debuggers accept the un-mangled name *if* it can resolve it. That may not be true for API functions you're calling without symbol files.