# Visual Studio 2008 C++: calling CDialog::Create() creates threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2008, mfc

My application is a MFC dialog-based app.  My app is shown having one thread until I call the `Create()` for the first of my four main windows (each a peer of the other and each parented to the desktop), at which point three more are created.

I then call `Create()` for three other windows, but don't get any more threads.

What are these threads and what is a good reference about them?  I don't seem them mentioned in the help on `CDialog::Create()`.

Comment: How is this question different from the one [you asked 2 hours ago](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35393611/1889329)? The answer will be the same, too: Those threads are implementation details you don't need to know about. They look out after themselves, and do not impact your application (assuming that it is correct). If you need to debug an error, don't go looking for the reason in any of those threads.

Comment: @Swiss Frank This is normal. Stop worrying about. Imagine a black box. You should take care about your own threads, only. And, as I said in your other post, if you want to catch your crash, activate Break on Exceptions

Comment: > How is this question different from the one you asked 2 hours ago?  

That question was about not a GUI thread, but some other thread with -8 priority.  Different threads, so different question about what the thread is.

In my career on Unix/Linux, knowing exactly what is going on behind the scenes has saved my bacon plenty of times.  Nowhere in this question am I talking about a bug or crash.  I'd simply like to know what's going on.  Maybe I'll learn a technique I should be using in my own code.  Maybe I see an accident waiting to happen.  Otherwise it may just satisfy my curiousity.

Comment: These may well be [thread pool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686760%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) related, and I agree with other commenters that there's little to learn by trying to dig too deep at the moment.